# How to change the uiculture or localization of webconfig in Azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, localization

I have written an MVC app where I can easily change the uiculture from the Web.config file.

```
<system.web>
    <globalization culture="fr-FR" uiCulture="fr-FR"/>
</system.web>
```

I have to host it in windows Azure. I have realized that you can configure app settings and connection strings from Azure but I cannot find anywhere that I can change the uiculture.

Any ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

In Windows Azure there isnt an explicit way to do that, as we do with connection strings.
if you want to do it you can do in startup task you would need to create a batch file (i.e. culture.cmd) in which can run the following command:

```
Appcmd set config /commit:WEBROOT /section:globalization /culture:fr-FR
Appcmd set config /commit:WEBROOT /section:globalization /uiCulture:fr-FR
```

After you have to create a startup task, defined in "ServiceDefinition.csdef":

```
<Startup>
 <Task commandLine="culture.cmd" executionContext="elevated" taskType="simple" />
</Startup>
```